# How can I add an item in a list from a JSON file in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, addition

I'm working with a JSON file and I was wondering if there's a way to append a string to a list within the file. Here's an example of the JSON file I'm working with:

```
{"language": "['English', 'French']", "bank": 50}
```

I want to add the string "Spanish" to the "language" list. How can I do this?

Here's the code I've written so far, but I'm not sure how to modify it to achieve what I want:

```py
import json

with open("example.json", "r") as jsonFile:
    data = json.load(jsonFile)

add list(data["language"]['Spanish'])

with open("example.json", "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```

How can I modify this code to achieve my goal?

Comment: `data["language"].append('Spanish')`, then save back to your file.

Comment: Are you sure that the `['English', 'French']` in your file is surrounded by double quotes? Because that seems an awkward, probably bad, choice of JSON structure. It also invalidates my suggestion above.

Comment: if i use " i have another error

Comment: Here is my json structure `{"language": "['English', 'French']", "bank": 50}`

Comment: Better to fix the input file to a more appropriate JSON format, then to fiddle around and doing weird things in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `{"language": "['English', 'French']", "bank": 50}`

Here the "language" keys hold a string rather than a list because of the `"` before `[` and `"` after `]`. To solve this, change the file to this:

`{"language": ["English", "French"], "bank": 50}`

Then use this code to append "Spanish" or any language from now on:

```
import json

with open("temp.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

data["language"].append("Spanish")

with open("temp.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
import ast

with open("example.json", "r") as jsonFile:
    data = json.load(jsonFile)

#data={"language": "['English', 'French']", "bank": 50}

#take a variable e

e=ast.literal_eval(data['language'])

e.append('Spanish')

data['language']=e

print(data)
#{'language': ['English', 'French', 'Spanish'], 'bank': 50}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what did you change? What is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75437797/edit), not here in comments (**** ***without*** **** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

In order to add to a Python list you should use the append() method.

Example:

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(data["language"]).append("Spanish")
```

Comment: This give me an error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: See my second comment to the question.

Comment: @BatteTarte if that's the case of list in double quotes you could:

`import ast

ast.literal_eval(data["language"]).append("Spanish")`

Comment: This not work @slqq it just end the terminal and nothing happened

Comment: *[literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)*: *"This is specifically designed not to execute Python code ... But it is* ***not free from attack***: *A relatively small input can lead to memory exhaustion or to C stack exhaustion, crashing the process. There is also the possibility for excessive CPU consumption* ***denial of service*** *on some inputs. Calling it on untrusted data is thus not recommended."*

Comment: Why is `literal_eval` needed at all?

Comment: I though we are speaking about a list of languages, which seems to be trusted data. I personally find `literal_eval` convinient to use in such case, trying to use what the language offer in builtin modules.